# UWP Coded UI Tests XamlWindow.Close() does not close the window

Tags: uwp, mstest, coded-ui-tests

I have a `ClassInitialize` method and a `ClassCleanup` method, I would like to launch the window on `ClassInitialize` (I got this working) and close the app on `ClassCleanup`.  When I launch the app in `ClassInitialize`, I store the `XamlWindow` so I can close it in `ClassCleanup`.

Here is my code:

```
static XamlWindow window;

[ClassInitialize]
public static void ClassInit(TestContext context)
{
    Playback.Initialize();
    window = XamlWindow.Launch("EagleBusinessSoftware.EBMSMyTime1.5_22ae44209eeep!App");
}

[ClassCleanup]
public static void ClassCleanup()
{
    window.Close();
}
```

But for whatever reason, `window.Close()` does nothing! The app doesn't close. I put a breakpoint in and verified that `window.Close()` was being hit, and indeed it was.

Any ideas on why this doesn't work? I've also tried using `window.CloseOnPlaybackCleanup = true` but that doesn't work either.